# How I can get props of class component reactjs (histort - location - match )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[I want to get props of home element, which is sent as a props to route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhmDP.png)

Comment: Please add code as text

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withRouter` HOC. [Documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)